# preventDefault - not working as i expect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, and my idea is send the data to a `validation.php` but without submitting the form. The code bellow simple does nothing when clicked. My problem is, I can't permit the submit default action because when the button is pressed, it reloads to the initial page regardless the validation valid or not in PHP. If I change `.click` to `.submit` the same occurs, the page is reloaded.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#customForm").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         $.post("validation.php", {
             nameRegist: $('#nameRegist').val(),
             emailRegist: $('#emailRegist').val(),
             myPasswordRegist: $('#myPasswordRegist').val(),
             pass2Regist: $('#pass2Regist').val()
         });
      });

   });
   </script>


<form method="post" id="customForm" action="">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name</label> 
                <input id="nameRegist" name="nameRegist" type="text" /> 
                <span id="nameInfo">Insira o seu nome</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">E-mail</label> 
                <input id="emailRegist" name="emailRegist" type="text" /> 
                <span id="emailInfo">Insira um email válido por favor!</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="myPassword">Password</label> 
                <input id="myPasswordRegist" name="myPasswordRegist" type="password" /> 
                <span id="myPasswordInfo">Insira pelo menos 4 letras e sem espaços</span>
                <div id="bar" style="width: 234px; height: 20px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="pass2">Confirm Password</label> 
                <input id="pass2Regist" name="pass2Regist" type="password" /> 
                <span id="pass2Info">Confirme a password</span>
            </div>
            <div></div>
            <div>
                <input id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="Send" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

http://emprego.xtreemhost.com/login/emprego.php - please click in the green button (registo) and then submit (sorry fot the bad server)

Comment: Shouldn't you `return false;`?

Comment: You're just posting the data without handling the callback? Have you confirmed that no JS errors are being reported?

Comment: How do you know nothing happens? You are not processing a response from the server. Have you checked with e.g. Firebug that no request is sent? If you want to use `.submit` (which is better) you have to attach the event handler to the form and not to the submit button. Actually, if it does nothing, this indicates that the code indeed works. Otherwise the site would reload.

Comment: i check the sintaxe and none error is detected. In the firebug the request is done when i press the button

Comment: Probably a stupid question but did you reference jQuery? Also there is no `.click` event for a form, you are better off using `.submit`.

Comment: as i said. If i use .submit() instead of .click() the page is reloaded

Comment: @Fel: On the form? Sure?

Comment: yes, this make the page reload $("#customForm").submit(function(event){    A simple alert do the same, reloads the page and none massage is showed

Comment: @Fel - I have nam: $('#nam').val(),
that does not look right

Comment: @Fel: Well, what message should be shown? You don't have any code that generates a message...

Comment: I get this error : name.val() is undefined

Comment: name.val is related to the homepage. i am really confused with this. I am thinking in change all code to the normal ajax. It is probably the best choice. @Felix at this step i simple want to avoid the reload of the page

Comment: the problem is the file validation.js - any conflict i don't know. Now works well, after deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $("#customForm").submit(function(event){
         $.post("validation.php", {
             nameRegist: $('#nameRegist').val(),
             emailRegist: $('#emailRegist').val(),
             myPasswordRegist: $('#myPasswordRegist').val(),
             pass2Regist: $('#pass2Regist').val()
         });
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
      });
   });
```

Comment: page reloaded. I will put the demo on the air